# C linked list passing list as argument to the function

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new with linked lists and I have a bug that I cannot find. I have single linked list filled with numbers which I send as argument to the function `search_tnode`. If function found the number that I'm searching for it returns and in main I can use new list starting with that number. If function does not find the number it returns and in main I have
empty list while I want to have original list that I sent as argument. How can I achieve this?

main:

```
my_list = search_tnode(my_list,key);
```

function:

```
struct t_node * search_tnode(struct t_node *start_time, unsigned long num){

    struct t_node *p;
    p = start_time;

    while(p != NULL){

        if(p->key == num){
            return p;
        }
        p = p->next;

    }

    printf("Number not found %ld \n",num);
    return start_time;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you call the function and it finds a node in the list, you return that node which you assign to the list head, thereby loosing everything before that node. Loosing nodes like that will most likely introduce memory leaks in your program.

I suggest two changes to fix this: First assign to some other variable, secondly if no node was found return `NULL` (it's customary), and check for that.

Comment: And third: use `%lu` instead of `%ld` for `unsigned long`s

Comment: I want to lose all nodes before node that I'm searching for. Where in code can I free them then ? And If I don't find the number I don't want empty list or NULL, I want to continue working on the original list that I passed. I didn't understand you how can I achieve this?

Comment: @user3852803 Then assign to a temporary variable, free all the nodes from the beginning to the new head (in the temporary variable) and *then* assign to the head variable.

Comment: What about my question if I don't find number in the list , why I have empty list in the main?

Comment: @user3852803 Unless you do something you don't show us, you shouldn't have an empty list. Perhaps you are returning `p` at the end in your actual code?

Comment: No , code above is my originally code, I'm returning start_time but in main I got empty list

Comment: @user3852803 And you're sure that you're not passing in `NULL` to begin with? Then I suggest you build a debug version, and run the program in a debugger. Set a breakpoint on that function, and step through it line by line, while keeping an eye on the variables.